# How to remove stop words and and tokenize

Tags: r, twitter

I've been doing analysis on twitter dataset and I'm stuck at a part where I need to convert data to tidy text and remove stop words. I did look up some websites but they throw error. Here's my code so far. Please help!

I don't know how to add csv file so I'm attaching image of my dataset. This is a very common dataset easily found on Kaggle etc.

[Final Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkmXl.png)

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(caret)
library(car)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
twitter_train<-read.csv("/Users/School/Documents/R/Final Training Data Set-twitter.csv")
text<-twitter_train$tweet
text <- tolower(text)
# Remove mentions, urls, emojis, numbers, punctuations, etc.
text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", text)
text <- gsub("https?://.+", "", text)
text <- gsub("\\d+\\w*\\d*", "", text)
text <- gsub("#\\w+", "", text)
text <- gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", text)
text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", text)
# Remove spaces and newlines
text <- gsub("\n", " ", text)
text <- gsub("^\\s+", "", text)
text <- gsub("\\s+$", "", text)
text <- gsub("[ |\t]+", " ", text)
#Create new column to store cleaned tweets
twitter_train["fix_text"] <- text
```

Comment: Can you please provide data, so we can replicate your error. Use `dput(twitter_train)` and copy output as code to your Question. And please provide the error you are receiving.

Comment: Link to CSV file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARqEt75G1UcUpfdBtae1yEvurydeE2vr/view?usp=sharing     My error is as follows:  > tidy_text <- twitter_train %>%
+   select(id,label,fix_text) %>%
+   #Tokenize the word from the tweets
+   unnest_tokens(input = fix_text, output = word) %>%
+   # Remove stop words
+   anti_join(stop_words, by="word")
Error in anti_join(., stop_words, by = "word") : 
  could not find function "anti_join"

Comment: OK. I ran the whole code and there is no error for me. I ran the last code as: `tidy_text <- twitter_train %>% select(id,label,fix_text) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(input = fix_text, output = word) %>% anti_join(stop_words, by="word") `

Comment: can you add `library(dplyr)` to your package list and run it again?

Comment: @Bloxx it worked! I was missing the library! Thank you so much.